# R: Loop a command to solve for a numeric variable that increases in each iteration until sum converges to a given integer

Tags: r

I have never used R to solve for a number by iteration. I searched for a solution with a "loop until" syntax and didn't succeed. Perhaps this could be done with something similiar to "fsolve" in Matlab.

I have the following (simplified) `data.table`:

```
head(db)
    client_id Price Quantity Ai_SR
1: 0100003801 2.802      160 197.2983
2: 0100003802 2.802      142 178.1377
3: 0100003803 2.802      240 196.0487
4: 0100003804 2.802       75 175.2219
5: 0100003805 2.802      145 208.5448
6: 0100010401 2.802      159 362.6629
```

Starting with `P_bar = 1`, I want to iterate the following command:

```
sum(db[, (Ai_SR * P_bar^(-0.15)) * P_bar])
```

*Until* `sum(db[, (Ai_SR * P_bar^(-0.15)) * P_bar]) = 8493853224`.

How do I write a command that does this by increasing `P_bar` by 0.01 in each iteration?

Moreover, I'm sure the sum will never exactly converge to `8493853224`. Therefore, I think I'll have to loop the command until the sum is strictly greater than `8493853224` and simply store the last `P_bar` before the sum was greater than `8493853224`.

I suppose I could copy and paste the command and replace `P_bar` by 1, 1.01, 1.02, ..., until the sum approached `8493853224`. Is there a *fancier* way of doing this?

I apologize if this question has been asked before. In my defense, I couldn't find anything similar by searching for loop-like solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do what you've described programatically is called a `while` loop, demonstrated in [djchapman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52599507/8386140). However, if you want to get even "fancier" (and much more efficient for big problems), you can just work the math:

Your goal is to find a `P_bar` such that the sum of all `db$Ai_SR[i] * P_bar^(-0.15) * P_bar` is equal to a particular constant (here 8493853224). Let that constant be *X*. Then

```
sum(db$Ai_SR * P_bar^(-0.15) * P_bar) = X 
sum(db$Ai_SR * P_bar^0.85) = X  
P_bar^0.85 * sum(db$Ai_SR) = X  
P_bar^0.85 = X / sum(db$Ai_SR)  
P_bar = (X / sum(db$Ai_SR))^(1/0.85)
```

While 8493853224 might be a reasonable number for your full dataset, for the six observations you posted, it's a bit high. So, let's use a more reasonable `X = 5000` for example:

```
## Read in the example data
db <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
 client_id Price Quantity Ai_SR
1: 0100003801 2.802      160 197.2983
2: 0100003802 2.802      142 178.1377
3: 0100003803 2.802      240 196.0487
4: 0100003804 2.802       75 175.2219
5: 0100003805 2.802      145 208.5448
6: 0100010401 2.802      159 362.6629")

## Apply the formula
(5000 / sum(db$Ai_SR))^(1/0.85)
# [1] 4.800361

## and check it against a naive while loop
P_bar <- 1
x <- sum(db$Ai_SR * (P_bar^0.85))
while ( x < 5000 ) {
  P_bar <- P_bar + 0.01
  x <- sum(db$Ai_SR * (P_bar^0.85))
}
P_bar
# [1] 4.81
```

Comment: I edited the post. I made a mistake. In reality, "Quantity" is a function of P_bar (my bad). With this edit, P_bar cannot be factored out nicely, which is why I need a `while` loop.

Comment: @ArturoSbr To be honest, I don't quite understand your formula as it's been edited. Do you mean that you want the sum of `P_bar^0.15 * P_bar * db$Ai_SR`?

Comment: For each row, I want to calculate `(Ai_SR * (P_bar^(-0.15))) * (P_bar)` and then sum over all the rows. In hopes of giving you a little more context, I'm just calculating the alternative consumption of each `client_id` given the demand function: `Q(P) = Ai_SR * P^(-0.15)`. As you can see, I'm just multiplying each Q(P) times P to and then summing over `i` to get the total revenue under a counterfactual demand function and a counterfactual price `P = P_bar`.

Comment: @ArturoSbr In that case, my approach is still 100% valid, though the calculation will change just a bit. Will update soon to reflect the new formula.

Comment: @ArturoSbr Updated to show the technique works even with your updated formula

Comment: You're absolutely right. I don't know why but I thought there was a plus sign inside the Q(P).

Answer (score 2):

```
calculation_max = 8493853224
step = 0.01
P_bar = 1 
while(calculation < calculation_max){
  calculation = sum(db[, Quantity * (P_bar^0.15)])
  P_bar = P_bar + step
}
```